# Export with blending options not accurate to what is on screen in Photoshop

Tags: blending, layer-style

My layer has a black background. I remove it with Blending Options on my Layer Style. On the left is my export, which still shows dark colors, but in Photoshop zoomed in, the dark colors are gone, which is the way I want it.

[image]

Why does the export appear incorrect?

Is there an alternative I can use to remove all black pixels from my layer?

Comment: Blending modes, especially as they relate transparency, do not work when exporting. You need to adjust artwork so blending modes aren't required over transparent areas.

Comment: How exactly do you export your image, in what format? This should've worked. Maybe consider uploading a file with the problem.

Comment: I am assuming the brown is not actually part of the image itself.

Comment: Blending is not a feature of a image format. It is a feature of the sioftware that shows the image. So the effect needs to be flattened, but this does not work with transparency in all cases.

Comment: It's surprising to me that blending modes do not work properly when exporting. I'd expect it to appear the same as it does in Photoshop.

I exported a png. I've tried both transparent and non-transparent.

Yes the brown is the background; not part of the image.

Flattenning the image makes the export appear correct. Why? Are we living in the 1990s? Do I need to flatten it, export, and undo the flatten every time I want a png of my psd?

Comment: Once again, it should've worked. Upload the file with the issue, otherwise it's impossible to say why it doesn't work for you